# Pulling a range of Values based on date range AND name

Tags: sql, r

I'm trying to calculate the average expenses of a particular site over a given period during which a client was active. The data held in 2 separate tables

df1=

| ClientID | DateStart | DateEnd | Site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-13 | 2020-02-15 | Albury |
| 2 | 2020-02-14 | 2020-02-15 | wodonga |

df2=

| Site | Date | Expense |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albury | 2020-02-13 | 4 |
| Albury | 2020-02-14 | 5 |
| Albury | 2020-02-15 | 7 |
| Albury | 2020-02-16 | 4 |
| Albury | 2020-02-17 | 4 |
| Wodonga | 2020-02-14 | 100 |
| Wodonga | 2020-02-15 | 120 |

I was hoping for this

| ClientID | DateStart | DateEnd | Site | Avg_exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-13 | 2020-02-16 | Albury | 5.3 |
| 2 | 2020-02-14 | 2020-02-15 | wodonga | 110 |

I'm using SQLDF in R, and have come up with following steps:

```
sqldf("select avg(Expense) from df1,df2 WHERE df2.Site= 'Albury' AND df2.Date >= df1.DateStart AND df2.Date <= df1.DateEnd")
```

This gives me the average expense for Albury for the period that Client 1 was active - which is what i would like to attach to ClientID 1.

To do this, I try to add a new column in df1 that returns the average expense if df1.Site = df2.Site

```
df1$Avg_exp = sqldf("select avg(Expense) from df1,df2 WHERE df2.Site= df1.Site AND df2.Date >= df1.DateStart AND df2.Date <= df1.DateEnd")
```

This just calculates the Average expense for the entire of df2.

I've also tried just putting out a new df where I have grouped the average expense by clientID, with the aim of then just joining it back to DF1

```
df3=sqldf("select avg(Expense) from df1,df2 WHERE df2.Site= df1.Site AND df2.Date >= df1.DateStart AND df2.Date <= df1.DateEnd GROUP BY df1.ClientID")
```

But I get the Error "Parameter 5 does not have length 2"

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that it really matters with this level of SQL code (it is standard enough across DBMSes), but I think the [tag:mysql] tag here is a distractor: if you are in fact using it as your SQL backend (there is no indication you are using anything other than the default of SQLite), your code does not state/suggest. Stack's tag recommendation system is imperfect, if the tag is real, please at least mention why, otherwise it is not right here.

Comment: Hi @r2evan thanks, I've removed the mysql tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is to use a left join for the two tables.
So you would get something like that:

```
SELECT df1.ClientId, df1.DateStart, df1.DateEnd, df1.Site, AVG(df1.Expense) as Avg_exp
FROM df1
LEFT JOIN df2 ON df2.Site = df1.Site
     WHERE df2.Date BETWEEN df1.DateStart AND df1.DateEnd
GROUP BY df1.ClientId, df1.DateStart, df1.DateEnd, df1.Site
```

Doing the above with a comparison over strings may not give you the expected result though. For example, 'wodonga' is not the same as 'Wodonga'.

Comment: I suggest you fix a couple of things with this answer: (1) typo, `ANG(.)` --> `AVG(.)`; and (2) your output is not going to match the expected output, since your code will require another join, I suggest you `select` (and `group by`) all of the other columns as well, not just `.Site`. Optionally (3) you can replace `>= ... <=` with `df2.Date between df1.DateStart and df1.DateEnd` for a little more concise/readable if functionally equivalent join code.

Comment: Such as `sqldf("select df1.ClientId, df1.DateStart, df1.DateEnd, df1.Site, avg(df2.Expense) as Avg_exp from df1 left join df2 on df1.Site=df2.Site and df2.Date between df1.DateStart and df1.DateEnd group by df1.ClientId, df1.DateStart, df1.DateEnd, df1.Site")`

Comment: thanks for that, the above worked. I'm curious whether I need to GROUP BY df1.DateStart and df1.DateEnd? If each ClientID and Site combination is unique, wouldn't that be enough for the "LEFT JOIN" function to get the right set of AVG values? I seem to get the same result without them.

Comment: All the fields that are returned by select must also be included in the group by statement. You might have the same result here because of the semantics of your data but that is not always the case. Some DBMS engines will actually raise an error if there is a mismatch.